# equation in math mode

Tags: math-mode

```
\begin{equation}

E-\epsilon_{i}-T_{i}-V_{0,i}(\textbf{R}) \tilde \chi_{i}^(+)(\textbf{K_{i}},\textbf{R})&=0


\end{equation}
```

Missing $ inserted and I don't know why. Can anybody help me?
thanks

Comment: Don't leave blank lines in math mode; LaTeX tries to interpret them as paragraph breaks, which aren't allowed in math mode.

Answer (score 9):

There are some issues in your equation:

1. The `&` character inside `equation` is not allowed (it is used for alignment in other math environments).
2. You can not leave blank lines inside an `equation`.
3. When you say `\textbf{K_{i}}` you are entering text mode and the `_` character is not allowed.
4. Also I think that in `\textbf{K_{i}}` you don't want the subscript to be bold.
5. If you want `(+)` to be a superscript you have to encase it in braces.

So, if you want bold letters in upright mode, substitute `\textbf` with `\mathbf`

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
E-\epsilon_{i}-T_{i}-V_{0,i}(\mathbf{R}) \tilde \chi_{i}^{(+)}(\mathbf{K}_{i},\mathbf{R})=0
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\mathbf{K}_{i}` is the correct syntax.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. I, too, think that the OP wanted to write that.