# Math equation eating whitespaces and operators

Tags: math-mode, equations

I have this:

```
$0.2 \mu sec = (1 − FR) * 0.1 \mu sec + (0.3 * FR) * 8 millisec + (0.7 * FR) * 20 millisec$ \\
```

and the result is that all whitespaces are gone, as well as the first minus symbol for example. If needed I can post a pic.

What should I do? This [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/169081/61180) did not help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The minus sign goes away because you're using the wrong character U+2212 instead of a simple hyphen.

Use `siunitx` facilities for inputting units.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\sisetup{text-micro=\textmu,math-micro=\text{\textmu}}

\begin{document}
\[
\SI{0.2}{\micro\second} =
  (1 - FR) * \SI{0.1}{\micro\second} + 
  (\num{0.3} * FR) * \SI{8}{\milli\second} + 
  (\num{0.7} * FR) * \SI{20}{\milli\second}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If *FR* denotes the name of a single variable, then it's better to use `\mathit` (as noted by Jonas Nyrup in the comments).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\sisetup{text-micro=\textmu,math-micro=\text{\textmu}}

\newcommand\FR{\mathit{FR}}

\begin{document}
\[
\SI{0.2}{\micro\second} =
  (1 - \FR) * \SI{0.1}{\micro\second} +
  (\num{0.3} * \FR) * \SI{8}{\milli\second} +
  (\num{0.7} * \FR) * \SI{20}{\milli\second}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Why is 1 not inside `\num`? Because it's a small integer, while `\num` is better used for numbers that may need some formatting. For instance, with

```
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}
```

one would automatically get a comma separator in the decimal numbers in `\num` or in `\SI`.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain why you use `\SI` and `\num`? Moreover, you have left the first 1 with nothing. Why?

Comment: you do not really need `\num` in that case. I guess Egrep use `\num` here because it can convert the decimal into national standard, and there is no decimal on `1`

Comment: Thanks @daleif. What about `/SI`?

Comment: `\SI` is for typesetting number together with units. 
Look at egreg's example how µs and ms are typeset upright instead of italics.
For more examples, have a look in the manual at page 6 and 7:
http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf

Comment: furthermore, if `FR` is a constant, some people prefer using `\mathit{FR}`, as it has a bit less space between F and R, to distinguish it from the product of two variables F and R.

Comment: @JonasNyrup You're right, but it's not clear what `FR` means.