# Align equation which floats to centre

Tags: equations, align

I have this code (which is based in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223438/61180) answer):

```
\[
\SI{0.2}{\micro\second} =
  (1 - FR) * \SI{0.1}{\micro\second} + 
  (\num{0.3} * FR) * \SI{8}{\milli\second} + 
  (\num{0.7} * FR) * \SI{20}{\milli\second}
\]
\[
\SI{0.2}{\micro\second} =
  \SI{0.1}{\micro\second} - 
  FR * \SI{0.1}{\micro\second} + 
  FR * \SI{2.4}{\milli\second} + 
  FR * \SI{14}{\milli\second}
\]
\[
\SI{0.1}{\micro\second} =
  -FR * \SI{0.1}{\micro\second} + 
  FR * \SI{2400}{\micro\second} + 
  FR * \SI{14000}{\micro\second}
\]
\[
\SI{0.1}{\micro\second} =
  -FR * \SI{16399.9}{\micro\second}
\]
\[
FR = 0.000006
\]
```

Output:

[image]

I would like every line to be in the same column, not centre-aligned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be you want to align them all at the `=` sign.

```
\documentclass{article}  %% preamble from egreg at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223438/11232
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\sisetup{text-micro=\textmu,math-micro=\text{\textmu}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\SI{0.2}{\micro\second} &=
  (1 - FR) * \SI{0.1}{\micro\second} +
  (\num{0.3} * FR) * \SI{8}{\milli\second} +
  (\num{0.7} * FR) * \SI{20}{\milli\second}\\
\SI{0.2}{\micro\second} &=
  \SI{0.1}{\micro\second} -
  FR * \SI{0.1}{\micro\second} +
  FR * \SI{2.4}{\milli\second} +
  FR * \SI{14}{\milli\second}\\
\SI{0.1}{\micro\second} &=
  -FR * \SI{0.1}{\micro\second} +
  FR * \SI{2400}{\micro\second} +
  FR * \SI{14000}{\micro\second}\\
\SI{0.1}{\micro\second} &=
  -FR * \SI{16399.9}{\micro\second}\\
FR &= \num{0.000006}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Reading `amsmath` manual goes a very long way in these times. To get it run `texdoc amsldoc` from command prompt/terminal.

Comment: You might want to add `\num{0.0000006}` just to be consistent in the formatting. `siunitx` can control what type of decimal point to use, this applies to `\SI` and `\num`.

Comment: Why are you using the `mu` setup? BTW: might also be an idea to include how to remove the decimal grouping.

Comment: @daleif Preamble is from egreg's answer and that mu setup gives a better mu IMO.

Comment: If grouping with numbers is un-wanted use `\num[group-digits=false]{0.000006}`  or globally `sisetup{group-digits=false}`

Comment: OK, I just find it strange looking.